# Any trick to add photo to empty contact names?

Tags: iphone, sms, ios, contacts.app

Many services (BlaBlaCar, Banks, train companies) send SMS messages with a "fake" sender name and empty number, and the new iOS 10 message list is quite boring and difficult to read with the same icon. I've found no ways to save these senders as new contacts and add them a photo. Any ideas??

*Update*:
As you can see in the attached screenshot many services use SMS for notifications and having some graphic icons would be VERY useful to recognize them at a glance - instead of all that "persons" icons - but they originate from a completely "empty" contact template (no real phone number), if I click on the person icon I don't see any data, so that adding this as a new contact is actually not linked to the SMS anyway.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try as:

1. Open Message app and open a particular SMS.
2. Tap Circular Person Icon at the top.
   [image: Circular Person Icon]
3. Tap `Create New Contact` option which will open a page where you can edit contact information and add a photo to the contact as well.

That's how you will be able to save a contact from message app and add a photo as well.
However, I couldn't understand your purpose/scenario quite clearly, so shed some more light onto your problem so that the community can answer your question accurately.

Comment: Updated question to show more info!

Comment: Unfortunately does not work, seemed a logical way and the contact is created but with no data, and not linked back to the SMS messages...